# trouble validating various inputs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

for a class project I have to build a website for a pet store, featuring a pet grooming service. This involves a form, php and a mysql server on my localhost. I have been unable to correctly validate this form via a jQuery validator plugin for some unknown (to me) reason.

I've had no luck via regular jQuery code beyond getting the form to not submit blank input values. So as it is, anybody can put 'sadklfhsdk' in any of the fields (except for email, unless it has a '@') and it will validate and submit to the server.

So after I going through a couple of tutorials this is what I have so far:

**The HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="h2Groom"><h2>Grooming Request Form</h2></div>
<form id="groom_form" method="post" action="insertPS.php">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <label for="firstName"><span>First Name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" class="required"/>
    </label> 
    <label for="lastName"><span>Last Name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" class="required"/>
    </label>   
    <label for="email"><span>Email Address:</span>
    <span id="error"></span>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter a Email"/>
    </label>
    <label for="phone"><span>Phone Number:</span>
    <span id="error"></span>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter a phone number" class="required"/>

    </label>    
    <label for="address"><span>Address:</span>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Enter your address" class="required"/>
    </label>   
    <label for="city"><span>City:</span>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter your city" />
    </label>    
    <label for="state"><span>State:</span>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="Enter your state" class="required"/>
    </label>   
    <label for="zipcode"><span>Zipcode:</span>
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" placeholder="Enter your zipcode" class="required"/>
    </label>

    <label for="petType"><span>Type of Pet:</span>
    <ul>
    <li><label><input name="petType" type="radio" value="dog" id="dog">Dog</label></li>
    <li><label><input name="petType" type="radio" value="cat" id="cat">Cat</label></li>
    <li><label><input name="petType" type="radio" value="bird" id="bird">Bird</label></li>
    </ul>
    </label>

        <select id="breed" name="breed">
            <option value="0">--Please Choose Dog Breed--</option>
            <option value="AlaskanMal">Alaskan Malamute</option>
            <option value="Bichon">Bichon Frise</option>
            <option value="WelshCorgi">Corgi, Welsh</option>
            <option value="Dalmation">Dalmation</option>
            <option value="EnglishToySpan">English Toy Spaniel</option>
            <option value="FrenchBull">French Bull Dog</option>
            <option value="Greyhound">Greyhound</option>
            <option value="Papillon">Papillon</option>
            <option value="Rottweiler">Rottweiler</option>
            <option value="YorkshireTerr">Yorkshire Terrier</option>
        </select>

    <label for="neut"><span>Check box if your pet has been neutered/spayed (leave unchecked if not).</span></label>
       <ul>
       <label>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="neut" id="neut" />Yes</li></label>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    <label for="petname"><span>Pet Name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="petname" id="petname" placeholder="Enter your pet's name" class="required" />
    </label> 
    <label for="petBday"><span>Pet's Birthday:</span>
        <input type="date" id="petBday" name="petBday"/>
    </label>

   <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <input type="submit" id="submitBttn" value="Submit" /><input type="reset" id="resetBttn" value="Reset" />

</form>
</body>
```

**The jQUERY (except the script to send values to server, see jsfiddle link):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=petType]').click(function() {
        if(this.id=='dog') {
            $('#breed').show('slow');
        }
        else {  
            $('#breed').hide('slow');
        }
    });

    $('input[name=phone]').blur(function() {
    if (validatePhone('phone')) {
        $('#error').html('Valid');
        $('#error').css('color', 'green');
    }
    else {
        $('#error').html('Invalid');
        $('#error').css('color', 'red');
    }
});

    $('input[name=email]').blur(function() {
        if (validateEmail('email')) {
            $('#error').html('Valid');
            $('#error').css('color', 'green');
        }
        else {
            $('#error').html('Invalid');
            $('#error').css('color', 'red');
        }
    });

    $("#submitBttn").click(function() { 
        //get input field values
        var user_firstName  = $('input[name=firstName]').val();
        var user_lastName   = $('input[name=lastName]').val();  
        var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var user_address    = $('input[name=address]').val();
        var user_phone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
        var user_city       = $('input[name=city]').val();
        var user_state      = $('input[name=state]').val();
        var user_zipcode    = $('input[name=zipcode]').val();
        var user_petname    = $('input[name=petname]').val();
        var checked_radio = $('input:radio[name=petType]').is(':checked');
        var user_neut = $('input:checkbox[name=neut]').is(':checked'); 
        var user_breed = $('input:select[name=breed]').is(':selected');
        var txtVal = $('#petBday').val();
        if(isDate(txtVal))
                alert('Valid Date');
            else
                alert('Invalid Date');      
    var proceed = true;
//Validation functions, executed when user hits "submit"

function validatePhone(phone) {
    var a = document.getElementById(phone).value;
    var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
    if (filter.text(phone)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function validateEmail(email) {
         var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(email)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
        }
    }
     function isDate(txtDate)
     {
        var currVal = txtDate;
        if(currVal == '')
        return false;

        //declare regex
        var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
        var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); //is the format ok?

        if(dtArray ==null)
        return false;

        //checks for mm/dd/yyyy format
        dtMonth = dtArray[1];
        dtDay = dtArray[3];
        dtYear = dtArray[5];

        if(dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12)
            return false;
        else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31)
            return false;
        else if ((dtMonth==4 || dtMonth==6 || dtMonth==9 || dtMonth==11) && dtDay ==31)
            return false;
            else if (dtMonth == 2)
            {
                var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
                if(dtDay > 29 || (dtDay ==29 && !isleap))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
     }
```

EDIT: corrected *if(filter.text())* to *if(filter.**test**(phone))*. None of my java validation code works.

Answer (score 0):

*validatePhone*:  filter.text should be spelled test

Comment: thank you catching that, but unfortunately it seems to not have fixed my problem